# Are Web APIs a javascript feature or a browser feature?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, webapi

MDN provides a [list of Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) available.

Are these Javascript feature or just limited to browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Limited to the browser. Say you are working on Node.Js, you will not find stuff like [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API) etc.